# Mysql запрос

Tags: sql

> `id`, `eventID`, `round`, `player1`,
> `player2`, `player3`, `player4`,
> `player5`, `time`

все поля int.
eventID + round - ключ, у каждого eventID максимально 30 раундов, может быть и меньше.
Подскажите как максимально **адекватно** найти наиболее часто встречающихся игроков.

Comment: Наиболее часто где?  

 - в таблице  
 - в эвенте  
 - в разных эвентах

Comment: Вообще полностью

Comment: Это статистика не большой игры, она вся пишется в одну табличку, в группе пять человек, если есть другие предложения рад выслушать.

Comment: @avengerweb, мои сомнения не умерли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Структура явно не годится для такого рода запросов.
В первом приближении к пониманию так:

```
select player, count(*) qty
from (
select player1 as player from table
union all
select player2 from table
union all
select player3 from table
union all
select player4 from table
union all
select player5 from table
) X
Group by player
order by qty desc limit 5
```

Comment: Предлагайте свою структура, как была бы лучше?

Comment: Как я могу предложить структуру, если не знаю предметной области и ее ограничений?
Исходя из общих соображений, должно быть 3 таких таблицы:
Игроки
Игры
Игроки_в_играх

Answer (score 2):

Когда я вижу поля подобно player_1...player_150, у меня зарождаются сомнения в правильности архитектуры БД.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд структуру

```
id, eventID, round, player1, player2, player3, player4, player5, time
```

Вы бы поменяли на следующую

**Playerss**

```
id, player
```

**Events**

```
id, eventID, round, player_id, time
```

А далее запрос который предложил [@msi](/users/2339/msi):

```
select player_id, count(*) as qty 
from table 
group by player_id 
order by qty desc limit 5
```

Comment: Не верно, в таблице ивент информация для каждого раунда, по вашей структуре кол-во записей увеличится в 5 раз в таблице с ивентами и еще придется цеплять таблицу плееров какой смысл

Comment: А почему это Вас так пугает? Смысл в том что такая структура более гибкая, как в плане логики, так и в плане формирования sql запросов. Да и не бывает такого чтобы ПЯТЬ игроков ОДНОВРЕМЕННО что-то сделали. Обязательно кто-то чуть раньше, кто-то чуть позже :-)

Comment: В данной ситуации группа из 5 игроков, убивает игровых боссов, несколько игровых боссов = eventID, после убийства заносится в БД, как пройденный раунд.